# Searching a large data file for a credit card type and its relevant info

Tags: regex, python-3.x, csv, while-loop

So I am running Python 3.7.1 and I am trying to make a program that pulls out only customers that use an American Express card and display only their name and Email. 
I have part of the code that pulls all the customers data that uses the same card type, but it pulls up multiple of the same name and email and all other information. I just can't figure out how to eliminate multiples and only display Name and Email. Below I will show a picture of my code and a screen shot of the output for reference.
[My code so far](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e49FI.png)

[Output(notice the multiples of Mary and Hunter)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3pXFw.png)

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention the file I am exporting from is an excel file if that really matters..

Comment: Instead of taking screenshots, consider pasting in the code and output as text. Easier to read and search.

Comment: Here is my code I tried something different it seems to work a little better but still not right. Code Below:                                                                                                  import csv
import re
data = []

with open("customerData.csv", "r") as csvfile:
    searchlines = csvfile.readlines()
for i, line in enumerate(searchlines):
    if "American Express" in line:
      line = True
      for l in searchlines[i:i+1]:
        data.append(l)
    else:
      line = False
print((data))

Comment: My output: ['Steve Bryan,male,544-48-7885,26/2/2012,(581) 372-8004,WV,61309,s.Bryan@ru.gov,American Express,3491xxxxxxx1481,02/17,male,WATT,2,$943.9000000
000001,3,$2099.83,8,$6030.52\n', 'Miss Sadie Bowman,female,946-87-2252,Wed Feb 28 2007 04:09:11 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time),(581) 417-2058
,CT,49692,s.bowmanowman@lu.gov,American Express,3438xxxxxxx7725,10/24,female,WOUA,3,$2127.17,8,$6801.3600000000015,16,$15945.040000000003\n', '
Alfred Ortega,male,362-63-3012,Tue Sep 18 2012 06:09:29 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time),6366743453,DE,49478-9297,a.Ortega@vacufwer.info,American Express

Comment: Plus about 400 more lines

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your file isn't extremely long, consider using Python's [`set`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#set) data structure to filter out duplicates. You can check for membership within the set via the `in` operator (e.g. `x in s`) and you can add new elements to the set via the `add()` method (e.g. `s.add(x)`). At a high level, you want to amend your code to check whether the element is already in your set (in which case you don't need to print it again), and if it is not in the set, add it to ensure you don't print it again.

Comment: It is a very large file is there a way I can use regular expressions to make it easier?

Comment: Do you specifically need to use python?

Comment: also how large is the file?

Comment: its a 216KB csv file

Comment: I am trying to get better with python and this was a problem posed by my class last term and its been bugging me because I cannot figure it out. I am a Cyber security major but im only in my second year and need to get my programming skills up.

Comment: At 216k you should be fine. It’s when you get into the hundreds of MB that you start running into trouble. Let me know how it works for you.